# Django query number of occurences of a character in CharField

Tags: python, django

I have a CharField who contains paths, like:
`zero/one/two/three` , or `root/usr/et_cetera`

The number of separators (here `/`) give us the depth of the 'node' in the path, so on the previous example, `three` has a depth of 3.

In python, I could write `'zero/one/two'.count('/')`, but I wonder how to do it in a Django query.

What I search is something like following:

```py
# Hypothetical code, does not work
Model.object.annotate(depth=CountChr('path', V('/'))).filter(depth=2)
```

I can't find a function who does that in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible by replacing all occurrences of the char we are looking for with a blank string, finding the length with the chars replaced and subtracting it from the original length

```
from django.db.models.functions import Replace, Length
from django.db.models import Value

Model.objects.annotate(depth=Length('path') - Length(Replace('path', Value('/')))).filter(depth__lt=2 + 1)
```

Comment: Work fine ! However it make the request very slow ... I will test the regex answer too. Thanks.I realize thanks to this answer that I have a lot to learn about complex requests with Djano. :)

Comment: Seems like using regex is appr 10x slow. I validate this answer, thanks!
Note: for performance, on my project i finally choose to store the depth for each 'node' into an integer. It make this request more than 20x faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django regex filter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#regex

You can try this or similar to this

```
Model.object.filter(path__regex=r'\w*\\w{2}')
```

Please try different regex patterns

Comment: it works fine with a regex like:
`reg = '^' + self.path + r'(/[A-Z0-9]+){,' + str(depth) + '}$'`
But its veeeery slow. (more than 10x the @Iain Shelvington reply )